# Excel Data Not Coming In An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, exceljs

I have a simple array, as shown in the image below

[image: Excel]

I want to get the office codes in an array. I am using the node `exceljs` module to achieve this

As per the example from the github page, I have this piece of code

```
 let array_is =[];
    let workbook = new excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile("path_to_file").then(()=>{
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
        var col = worksheet.getColumn(1);
        console.log(col.values);
        array_is = array_is.push(col.values);
    });

    console.log(array_is);
```

However, the array returns `[]`. If I print the values from the excel alone using a `console` statement, the I am able to see the values printed from the excel correctly.

What am I doing wrong in pushing the values to an array. I have also using the `toString()` method in the array push statement but the array was not populated.

Comment: my bad. Should've tagged javascript.

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvotes?

Comment: Just a hunch: Your desired index in `getColumn` could be 0 instead of 1 (zero indexed approach as typical in Javascript and many other languages).

Comment: Nope. Index is 1 only. I tried with `0` but it doesn't picks up anything.

Answer (score 0):

`array_is` is placed outside the `workbook.xlsx.readFile` that's the main issue here. `workbook.xlsx.readFile` is an asynchronous function, so the code flow advances to the next statement without waiting for the completion of current line. So log your `array_is` inside the readFile function.

```
let array_is =[];
let workbook = new excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("path_to_file").then(()=>{
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    var col = worksheet.getColumn(1);
    console.log(col.values);
    array_is = array_is.push(col.values);
    console.log(array_is);
});
```